# How to pass all records from result using JSCONArray

Tags: android

i am trying to import Mysql column in andorid column here is my php file which getting column values it  showing me all records
like this

```
[{"nome":"A BARATEIRA DE TECIDOS LIMITADA ME"}][{"nome":"A BARATEIRA DE TECIDOS LIMITADA ME"},{"nome":"A.A.L. COMESTIVEIS E RESTAURANTE LTDA ME"}][{"nome":"A BARATEIRA DE TECIDOS LIMITADA ME"},{"nome":"A.A.L. COMESTIVEIS E RESTAURANTE LTDA ME"},{"nome":"ACOUGUE E MERCEARIA COSTELAO DA SERRA LTDA ME"}]"
```

//my php file

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","abcd");
mysql_select_db("fabricacao");
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM cliente ORDER BY NOME") ;
$nome ='nome';
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$output[]=$rows;
 print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

my problem is here when i am converting records of result into Array then  JSONArray.lenght() showing 'size =1' and inseting just first one record, i dont understand where is problem i want store all rows ?

```
try
{
   JSONArray  jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  //mydb
       sql= openOrCreateDatabase("CLT",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
       ContentValues values=new ContentValues(); 
       int n = jArray.length();
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        values.put("CLIENT", json_data.getString("nome"));
         sql.insert("clnt", null, values);
        }
       sql.close();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Erro",e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your result data into arraylist and then add it into your db. check the below code for getting all the records coming from the database.

```
 try{

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


            ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name=json_data.getString("name");
                     your_array_list.add(name);


                                    }

    }
    catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
```